# Preloader image shows on my local host but not showing after deployed on my github?

Tags: web, preloader, image-preloader

I created preloader on my website using jquery. Preloader shows on my local host properly but not showing after deployed on github. I mean preloader background works properly. But loading image does not show. If anyone knows please let me know!